# Remove All Adjacent Duplicates In String in C++: Why is my iterator not entering into the for loop again

Tags: c++, arrays, string, replace

https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-all-adjacent-duplicates-in-string/

In this Leetcode question, I tried to do it without using the concept of a stack. But according to the answer, I get the loop is not getting completed, why is that the case here?

```
class Solution {
    public:
    string removeDuplicates(string s) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            if(s[i] == s[i+1]){
                s.erase(i,2);
                i=0;
            }
            
        }
        
        return s;
    }
};
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Seems like the questioner is about to learn some valuable lessons about array boundary condition testing and undefined behavior.  That’s not nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your loop boundary, `i < s.length()`, is wrong since it'll let `s[i + 1]` access the string out of bounds<sup>*</sup>.
- You need to reset `i` when a match is found, which you do, but it's followed by `i++` directly, so it will never find a match at `s[0] == s[1]` again.

Fixed:

```cpp
string removeDuplicates(string s) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i + 1 < s.length();) { // corrected loop bounds
        if (s[i] == s[i + 1]) {
            s.erase(i, 2);
            i = 0;
        } else ++i;                            // only add 1 if no match is found
    }
    return s;
}
```

<sup>*</sup> The out of bounds access will really access the terminating `\0` (since C++11, *undefined behavior* before that), but it's unnecessary since you can't `erase` it anyway.

---

A somewhat quicker version would be to not reset `i` to `0`, but to continue searching at the current position. You may also use [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) to simplify the algorithm:

```cpp
string removeDuplicates(string s) {
    for(auto it = s.begin(); (it = std::adjacent_find(it, s.end())) != s.end();) {
        it = s.erase(it, it + 2);
        if(it != s.begin()) --it; 
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: BTW, the reset `i = 0` might be reduced: `i = (i == 0 ? 0 : i - 1)` as range `[0; i-1)` has already been checked, just last character has to be re-tested.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I just added a version of that (except I made it search from the end instead and did `++i` to compensate for `i--`).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++) {
    if(s[i] == s[i+1]){
        s.erase(i,2);
        i=0;
    }
    
}
```

is that after erasing two adjacent elements the variable `i` is set to `0` within the if statement and then at once is incremented in the for statement. So in the next iteration of the loop the variable `i` is equal to `1`.

Consider the following string

```
"abba'
```

after erasing `"bb"` the string becomes equal to `"aa"` but after that the variable `i` is equal to `1` and in the next iteration of the loop you are comparing `s[1]` and `s[2]` that are `'a'` and `'\0'`.

Rewrite the loop at least the following way

```
for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.length(); ) 
{
    if ( s[i] == s[i+1] )
    {
        s.erase(i,2);
        i=0;
    }
    else
    {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C++ Standard `s[s.length()]` is equal to `'\0'`. So you may use the comparison `s[i] == s[i+1]`. According to the assignment in the provided link the string contains only low case letters.